# Create a Backend services for an App Engine Load balancer

Tags: google-app-engine, websocket, gcp-load-balancer

We want to create a [backend service](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/backend-service) for our Flex App engine.

in the cloud logs and my GCP invoice, I can see that I already have an HTTP load balancer, but when I go to network services -> Load balancing I don't find my load balancer.

[image]

I think the load balancer is auto-created by GCP once you create an APP engine. But How can I create a back End service to it. the goal is to customize the Load balancer to better handle web sockets time-outs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, App Engine handles the load balancer automatically.  While this is very convenient it means that you can't modify the load balancer to use a backend service.

To accomplish this, you'll need to create and configure your own load balancer.  I've never done this but I expect that a kubernetes cluster could be used.